# How to switch the id of an attribute on button click

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-app

I am currently writing a chrome app (Not to be confused with an extension. Yes chrome apps still exist [only on Chromebooks]). Anyways, I need to change a circles id which will change the css animation to a green dot instead of a red dot. Here is my code:

HTML (before):

```
<div class="circle" id="redcircle"></div></td>
<button type="button" id="clickme">Unlock</button></td>
```

HTML (I need it to look like this when I click the button):

```
 <div class="circle" id="greencircle"></div></td>
    <button type="button" id="clickme">Unlock</button></td>
```

CSS:

```
#redcircle {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: Fade01;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#greencircle {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: Fade02;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
@keyframes Fade01 {
    0% {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
    50% {background-color: #FF0000;}
    100% {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
}
@keyframes Fade02 {
    0% {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
    50% {background-color: #00FF00;}
    100% {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I strongly recommend to use classes instead of IDs for green and red, and use IDs that will NOT change (i.e. you can address the elements by ID and change their class). Also i can't imagine how to NOT use Javascript for a task like this.

Comment: okay thanks I will refer to them as classes and try some inline javascript

Comment: Note, inline is forbidden so use a separate file loaded via a script tag.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about that and that solved the security problem.